# stack dump from Lua side

Tags: lua

is it possible to dump the stack on the Lua side ( not the C/C++ side)?

similar to this but from Lua side

```
static void stackDump (lua_State *L) {
          int i=lua_gettop(L);
          printf(" ----------------  Stack Dump ----------------" );
          while(  i   ) {
            int t = lua_type(L, i);
            switch (t) {
              case LUA_TSTRING:
                printf("%d:`%s'", i, lua_tostring(L, i));
              break;
              case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
                printf("%d: %s",i,lua_toboolean(L, i) ? "true" : "false");
              break;
              case LUA_TNUMBER:
                printf("%d: %g",  i, lua_tonumber(L, i));
             break;
             default: printf("%d: %s", i, lua_typename(L, t)); break;
            }
           i--;
          }
         printf("--------------- Stack Dump Finished ---------------" );
    }
```

Comment: You mean the call stack? There is no value stack on the Lua side. The closest thing is the set of active locals. You can use the debug library for looking at those.

Comment: There is literally no values stack on lua side.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the debug library can help you.For example, we will get the call stack by [debug.getinfo](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo)